# ruby active_record-acts_as gem: getting correct child from parent instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, dynamic, polymorphism

I'm using active_record-acts_as gem to implement multiple table inheritance. My scenario:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
   actable
end

class Plane < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as :Vehicle
end

class Train < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as :Vehicle
end
```

Whenever I create an instance of Plane or Train, a corresponding Vehicle is created.

I'm developing an API, so upon listing Vehicles I will return the fields in Vehicle model. However, when I receive GET /Vehicles/1 I want to return the actual vehicle, whether it's a Plane, a Train, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class VehiclesController
  def show
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:id]).specific
  end 
end
```

Since both Plane and Train "extend" Vehicles in the MTI sense you can get the record by querying `Vehicle`. `.specific` gives you the actual Plane or Train instance instead of the parent type.

Comment: That is correct! I totally misunderstood that method when I read it on the gem's documentation